# problems with UTF-8 encoding in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

The characters I am getting from the URL, for example www.mydomain.com/?name=john , were fine, as longs as they were not in Russian.

If they were are in Russian, I was getting '����'.

So I added $name= iconv("cp1251","utf-8" ,$name); and now it works fine for Russian and English characters, but screws up other languages. :)))

For example 'Jānis' ( Latvian ) that worked fine before iconv, now turns into 'jДЃnis'.

Any idea if there's some universal encoder that would work with both the Cyrillic languages and not screw up other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this runs down to the problem of how the URL is encoded. If you're clicking a link on a given page the browser will use the page's encoding to sent the request but if you enter the URL directly into the address-bar of your browser the behavior is somehow undefined as there is no standardized way on the encoding to use (Firefox provides an `about:config` switch to use UTF-8 encoded URLs).

Besides using some encoding detection there is no way to know the encoding used with the URL in the given request.

**EDIT:**

Just to backup what I said above, I wrote a small test script that shows the default behavior of the five major browsers (running Mac OS X in my case - Windows Vista via Parallels in case of the IE):

```
$p = $_GET['p'];
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($p); $i++) {
    // this displays the binary data received via the URL in hex format
    echo dechex(ord($p[$i])) . ' ';
}
```

Calling `http://path/to/script.php?p=äöü` leads to

- Safari (4.0.5): `c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc`
- Firefox (3.6.3): `c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc`
- Google Chrome (5.0.375.38): `c3 a4 c3 b6 c3 bc`
- Opera (10.10): `e4 f6 fc`
- Internet Explorer (8.0.6001.18904): `e4 f6 fc`

So obviously the first three use UTF-8 encoded URLs while Opera and IE use ISO-8859-1 or some of its variants. **Conclusion**: you cannot be sure what's the encoding of textual data sent via an URL.

Comment: I highly doubt this is related to browser encoding, my guess would be the content-type header is not using the utf-8 charset.

Comment: That depends on how exactly he's calling his PHP script. If he enters `http://www.mydomain.com/?name=Делать` into the browser's address bar, it will be a browser encoding problem as he will not know which encoding is used to send the request. If he clicks a link with the mentioned `href` for example, I'm with you - then it's the page's encoding that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Tried it and in FF 3.6 it outputs gibberish either way, if I set up Content-Type correctly both scenarios work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. It appears fine if it is a clicked link, versus just typed in URL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use UTF-8 with all files and processes?

Comment: aaa... how do I do it? * embarrassed *

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: it's an answer. obvious enough to be phrased in the form of question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is the file encoding, you should always use **UTF-8 no BOM** as the prefered encoding for your `.php` files, code editors such as **[Intype](http://intype.info/stain.html)** let you easily specify this (UTF-8 Plain).

[image]

**Also, add the following code to your files before any output:**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

---

**You should also read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky.**